# ошибка публикации записи с телефона

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

В iframe-приложении вк вызываю метод:

```
VK.api("wall.post", {"owner_id": "-133100845",message:post_text,attachments:photos1}, function (data) {   
////
});
```

Все работает с компьютера, а если запускать с андроид-клиента вк, то выдает ошибку: [image: ошибка]

В документации написано, что это означает, что доступ к методу запрещен. Но почему? Как починить?